# Unexecpted white frame around Cardview on KitKat but not on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-cardview, appearance

I have an unexplained white frame of 1 or 2 dp thick around my cardview on kitkat. This white frame does not appear on Lollipop, which is what I expect.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/podcasts_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    cardview:cardElevation="5dp">
```

Please note that colorPrimary theme attribute is dark blue and that i am using :

```
cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

which takes care of the padding issue over platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too. Try calling:

```
setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
```

on the CardView. That is what worked for me.

Also - you may not need `cardUseCompatPadding = "true"`

Comment: Thanks Maggie . It solved the problem. I used related XML attributes cardPreventCornerOverlap.

Comment: I used XML attributes cardPreventCornerOverlap but i got this error    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1